# Expected value for number of occurences

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let $W$ be a random word made from letters which are in set $K$ (letters are uniformly distributed in $W$) . Suppose also that $W$ has finite length ($\geq 2$) and size of $K$ is finite ($\geq 2$).

Let $W'$ be a word such that it has at least two letters and its last letter is not same as the first one. What is expected value for number of occurrences of $W'$ in $W$?

**Bonus**: What if the first letter is same as the last letter?

Comment: With occurrence you mean *disjoint* occurrences, right? I mean, for instance `baba` is included only once in `bababa`, not twice, right?

Comment: Yeah, disjoint occurences.

Comment: What have you tried?  You might use, for example, indicator functions, or recursion. Are you sure it is _disjoint occurrences_?  There is a simpler answer if not.  If you are looking for disjoint occurrences, I think you will need more info about the amount of overlap possibilities in $W'$. For example, for the disjoint case, $baaa$ will give a different answer than $baba$.